# Offset between two array element addresses in C

Tags: c, arrays, offset

I have a question asking me to find the offset in bytes between two array element addresses:

> ```
> double myArray[5][7];
> ```
>
> If C stored data in column-major order the offset (in bytes) of `&myArray[3][2]` from `&myArray[0][0]` would be:

In column major order, I think elements would be laid out as such:

```
[0][0] -- [1][0] -- [2][0] -- [3][0] -- ..... -- [3][2]
```

So in my mind to get the offset in bytes is to count the number of jumps between [0][0] and [3][2] and times that by 8 since it's an array of doubles. However, what's confusing me is that it's asking for the offset using the & operator. Would this somehow change the answer since it's asking between two addresses or is the process still the same? I think it'd be the same but I'm not 100% certain.

If my thinking is correct would this then be 8*15 bytes?

Comment: Without the & those expressions would yield *values* and not addresses.

Comment: Correct, but would the process change with finding the offset between the two memory locations? I suppose what I'm saying is that the framing of the question is confusing me as to whether I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to find the offset between 3.14 and 2.78. "Offset" only makes sense with memory addresses.

Comment: Well I was assuming the possibility of framing the question as "the offset between elements [3][2] and [0][0]" and perhaps the address part could just be assumed. In any case, are you telling me that my method is the correct approach?

Comment: I think the author of the question just wanted to ask it in a more C-like manner. You should be able to test this with: `printf("%d\n", (char*)&myArray[3][2] - (char*)&myArray[0][0]);`

Comment: In order for that print statement to be correct I'd have to make sure it was in column-major order, right?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. C stores data in row-major order. I think I'm just making matters worse, sorry.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate the help very much.

Comment: "would this then be 8*15 bytes?"  Try code and see: `double myArray[5][7]; printf("%d\n", (int) ((&myArray[3][2] - &myArray[0][0]) * sizeof myArray[0][0]));`

Comment: [don't put code in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714). I've fixed it for you this time

Answer (score 4):

The memory lay out for the 2d array would be a contiguous chunk of memory.(Based on your question)

```
int x[2][3] = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5}};
```

That will be layed out in (Your question)

```
--+--+--+--+--+--+
 0| 3| 1| 4|2 |5 |
--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

But in `C` this is stored like

```
--+--+--+--+--+--+
 0| 1| 2| 3|4 |5 |
--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

Now you are absolutely right, that you can consider jumps between `[0][0]` and `[3][2]` but there is a better way to do that without thinking about all this, you can be sure that their offset will be their address differences.

You can simply get their addresses and subtract them.

`ptrdiff_t ans = &a[3][2]-&a[0][0]`;(this is basically the gaps between the two elements)

That yields the answer. `printf("answer = %td",ans*sizeof(a[0][0]);` (One gap = `sizeof(a[0][0])`) [In your case `double`]

Or even better way would be to

```
ptrdiff_t ans = (char*)&a[3][2] - (char*)&a[0][0];//number of bytes between them.
```

---

I will explain a bit why `char*` is important here:

<strike>`(char*)&a[0][0]` and `&a[0][0]` both contain the same thing *value-wise*.</strike>(this is not general enough)

But it matters in pointer arithmetic. (Interpretation is different).

When not using the cast, the interpretation is of the data type of array elements. That means now it consider the difference in `double`s. When you cast it, it spits the result in or difference in `char`-s.

And why this works? Because all data memory is `byte` addressable and `char` is of single bytes.

---

There is something more to this than expected , first let's see what is an array in `C`? **<sup>†</sup>**

*C does not really have multi-dimensional arrays*. In `C` it is realized as an array of arrays. And yes those multidimensional array elements are stored in row-major order.

To clarify a bit more we can look into an example of standard **§6.5.2.1**

Consider the array object defined by the declaration

```
      int x[3][5];
```

> Here `x` is a `3 x 5` array of `int`s; **more precisely, `x` is an array of
>   three element objects, each of which is an array of five `int`s**. In the
>   expression `x[i]`, which is equivalent to `(*((x)+(i)))`, **`x` is first
>   converted to a pointer to the initial array of five ints**. Then `i` is
>   adjusted according to the type of `x`, which conceptually entails
>   multiplying `i` by the size of the object to which the pointer points,
>   namely an array of five int objects. The results are added and
>   indirection is applied to yield an array of five ints. When used in
>   the expression `x[i][j]`, that array is in turn converted to a pointer
>   to the first of the `int`s, so `x[i][j]` yields an int.

So we can say `double myArray[5][7];` here `myArray[3][2]` and `myArray[0][0]` are not part of the same array.

Now that we are done here - let's get into something else:

From standard **§6.5.6.9**

> When two pointers are subtracted, **both shall point to elements of the
>   same array object**, or **one past the last element** of the array object;
>   the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array
>   elements.

But here `myArray[3]` and `myArray[0]` are denoting two different arrays. And that means `myArrayp[3][2]` and `myArray[0][0]` both belong to different arrays. And they are not one past the last element. **So the behavior of the subtraction `&myArray[3][2] - &myArray[0][0]` will not be defined by the standard.**

**<sup>†</sup>**<sub>Eric (Eric Postpischil) pointed out this idea.</sub>

Comment: I see, as  I asked before, that print statement would only work correctly so long as our array was made to be column-major, right? So perhaps I'd have to allocate on the heap in column-major order since C by default makes stack arrays in row-major?

Comment: @dj1121.: It works even if the memory layout is row major order or column major order- but yes ofcourse the value of `ans` differs - as on your word the `jump` is different.

Comment: It was requested to answer in bytes, your code answers in ints

Comment: So would the number of bytes in this case be 8*15?

Comment: @dj1121.: It will be `sizeof(x[0][0])*ans` or `sizeof(double)*ans`

Comment: Technically, the behavior of `&a[3][2]-&a[0][0]` is not defined by the C standard. Pointer operands to the `-` operator must point to objects in the same array (or one past the last element), and `a[3]` and `a[0]` are different arrays.

Comment: @EricPostpischil.: Can I reply you a bit later when I am home? It seems it will be an interesting discussion. A small thing...though..a[3] and a[0] are different or part of same 2d array?

Comment: Sure. `a[3]` and `a[0]` are elements of the same array, `a`, but `a[3][2]` and `a[0][0]` are not. They are elements of different arrays.

Comment: @EricPostpischil.: Is there anyway you can identify that `a[3][0]` and `a[0][0]` are parts of different array. Because everything is on same 2d array. So isn;t that enough criterial to be `in the same array and applicable to pointer arithmetic`?

Comment: @coderredoc: C does not have 2D arrays. It has arrays, the elements of which can be other arrays. In this situation, C views `a` as an array of elements whose type is array of `int`. `a[3][2]` is not an element of `a`. It is an element of `a[3]`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil.: Can you check the answer once?

Comment: @coderredoc: Writing about technical details of the C specification is tricky. I have been working with it for many years (decades, I suppose) and still get things wrong.

Comment: @EricPostpischil.: Yes that's really the case. And I suppose why the standard committee don't clear things up. If they write in more easy  manner then it will be easier. But given the volume of work I guess that's hardly possible. For this answer do you think any modification is needed? And really thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In a row-major traversal, the declaration is `array[height][width]`, and the usage is `array[row][column]`. In row-major, stepping to the next number gives you the next column, unless you exceed the width and "wrap" to the next row. Each row adds `width` to your index, and each column adds 1, making rows the "major" index.

In order to get the column-major equivalent, you assume the next value is the next row, and when the row exceeds the height, it "wraps" to the next column. This is described by `index = column * height + row`.

So, for an array `array[5][7]` of *height* 5, the index `[3][2]` yields `2*5 + 3 = 13`.

Let's verify with some code. You can get column-major behavior simply by switching the order of the indices.

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                             

int main() {                                                                                                                   
    double array[7][5];                                                                                                    
    void *root = &array[0][0];                                                                                             
    void *addr = &array[2][3];                                                                                             
    size_t off = addr - root;                                                                                              
    printf("memory offset: %d number offset: %d\n", off, off/sizeof(double));                                                                        
    return 0;                                                                                                              
}
```

Running this program yields an address offset of 104, or 13 doubles.

EDIT: sorry for wrong answer

Comment: The question asks about offset to `[3][2]`, not to `[2][3]`. And don't attempt to print `size_t` values with `%d`.

Comment: My code transforms the row-major nature of C to column-major by switching those values.

Comment: Um... "column-major" is a synonym of "row-wise". Both  are correct ways to describe natural 2D array layout in C. There's no need to "transform" anything.

Comment: Also, C language does not support pointer arithmentic on `void *` pointers. Your `addr - root` is illegal in C.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order
"In a row-major order, the consecutive elements of a row reside next to each other". Also, my arithmetic is totally legal. EDIT: it's a GNU extension. [shrugs]

Comment: OK, I take it back. There must be some confusion about terminology on my part. I assumed that "column-major" means that *major index* (first index) is column index. Apparently, something else was meant in this case. Still, your arithmetic in **not** legal. C language does not allow pointer arithmentic on pointers to incomplete types, including `void *` pointers (see for yourself http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a3ba81d2632420a)

Comment: @SamPagenkopf, thank you for your answer. Is there a way you'd suggest thinking about this on paper perhaps? I switched indices and then followed the same method as I did in my original question of counting the number of jumps from the start to end address and then times that by 8. But, I think that gives me the wrong answer.

Comment: Take a 5x7 grid, and fill it with increasing numbers starting at 0. Moving left-to-right, top-to-bottom is row-major, and top-to-bottom, left-to-right is column-major. The upper-left space is row 0, col 0. For a given row and col, the number in that space is your offset.

Answer (score 0):

## The Simple Answer

C does not have multidimensional arrays, so we have to interpret `double myArray[5][7]` as one-dimensional array of one-dimensional arrays. In `double myArray[5][7]`, `myArray` is an array of 5 elements. Each of those elements is an array of 7 `double`.

Thus, we can see that `myArray[0][0]` and `myArray[0][1]` are both members of `myArray[0]`, and they are adjacent members. Thus, the elements proceed `[0][0]`, `[0][1]`, `[0][2]`, and so on.

When we consider `myArray[1]`, we see it comes after `myArray[0]`. Since `myArray[0]` is an array of 7 `double`, `myArray[1]` starts 7 `double` after `myArray[0]`.

Now we can see that `myArray[3][2]` is 3 arrays (of 7 `double`) and 2 elements (of `double`) after `myArray[0][0]`. If a `double` is 8 bytes, then this distance is 3•7•8 + 2•8 = 184 bytes.

## The Correct Answer

To my surprise, I cannot find text in the C standard that specifies that the size of an array of *n* elements equals *n* times the size of one element. Intuitively, it is “obvious”—until we consider that an implementation in an architecture without a flat address space might have some issues that require it to access arrays in complicated ways. Therefore, we do not know what the size of an array of 7 `double` is, so we cannot calculate how far `myArray[3][2]` is from `myArray[0][0]` in general.

I do not know of any C implementations in which the size of an array of *n* elements is not *n* times the size of one element, so the calculation will work in all normal C implementations, but I do not see that it is necessarily so according to the C standard.

## Calculating the Distance in a Program

It has been suggested the address can be calculated using `(char *) &myArray[3][2] - (char *) &myArray[0][0]`. Although this is not strictly conforming C, it will work in common C implementations. It works by converting the addresses to pointers to `char`. Subtracting these two pointers then gives the distance between them in units of `char` (which are bytes).

Using `uintptr_t` is another option, but I will omit discussion of it and its caveats as this answer is already too long.

## A Wrong Way to Calculate Distance

One might think that `&myArray[3][2]` is a pointer to `double` and `&myArray[0][0]` is a pointer to `double`, so `&myArray[3][2] - &myArray[0][0]` is the distance between them, measured in units of `double`. However, the standard requires that pointers being subtracted must point to elements of the same array object or to one past the last element. (Also, for this purpose, an object can act as an array of one element.) However, `myArray[3][2]` and `myArray[0][0]` are not in the same array. `myArray[3][2]` is in `myArray[3]`, and `myArray[0][0]` is in `myArray[0]`. Further, neither of them is an element of `myArray`, because its elements are arrays, but `myArray[3][2]` and `myArray[0][0]` are `double`, not arrays.

Given this, one might ask how `(char *) &myArray[3][2] - (char *) &myArray[0][0]` can be expected to work. Isn’t it also subtracting pointers to elements in different arrays? However, character types are special. The C standard says character pointers can be used to access the bytes that represent objects. (Technically, I do not see that the standard says these pointers can be subtracted—it only says that a pointer to an object can be converted to a pointer to a character type and then incremented successively to point to the remaining bytes of an object. However, I think the intent here is for character pointers to the bytes of an object to act as if the bytes of the object were an array.)